# A wrong configuration in Geometry?

Tags: geometry, contest-math

The mid-point of the hypotenuse of a right angled triangle ABC, right angled at B is M. A line is drawn perpendicular to the hypotenuse through M, in such a way, that the portion of it lying inside the triangle is 3 cm long and outside the triangle, up to the other side is 9 cm. Find the length of the hypotenuse.

I do not understand what is meant by part lying inside the triangle and outside, won't part outside be infinite?

Could someone please explain what this question wants and give a hint please?

Comment: Is it possible that the question intends for that perpendicular line to intersect the extension of one of the sides of the triangle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my interpretation is correct, here is a diagram:

[image]

To solve for $x$, simply note that $\triangle CME \sim \triangle DMA$.

Comment: thanks so much for this answer

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I think the question means that $DE = 3, EF = 9$.

Hint: you have two pairs of similar triangles that lead to the answer.

Comment: thanks so much!

Comment: You are welcome!